# Cannot insert the value NULL in a identity id

Tags: php, sql, t-sql, insert, identity

Here's the table. I need the id to increment automatically.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Atable](
    [id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [CaseNo] [int] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [AtablePK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Atable ON
```

And here's the insert procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.INSERT_Atable
  @id INT = NULL OUTPUT
 ,@CaseNo INT = NULL 

AS
 SET NOCOUNT OFF;

 SELECT  @id = @@IDENTITY 

 INSERT INTO dbo.Atable(id,CaseNo)  VALUES(@id ,@CaseNo)
```

And here's the call to the procedure:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.INSERT_Atable ON
 EXEC dbo.Atable  @CaseNo = '2'
```

Why am I getting This error?:

```
 Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'dbo.Atable'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you having an `IDENTITY` column, then it gets assigned a value automatically.

Don't include it in the `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Atable(CaseNo) 
     VALUES(@CaseNo);
```

Comment: If I detele the id in the insert I get: Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'Atable' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.

Comment: There is an exception if `IDENTITY_INSERT` is `ON`.  However, that is special purpose functionality, used when you want to copy over data into another table, without affecting the identity column.

Answer (score 0):

`IDENTITY` column is automatically incremented. You just need to specify the *starting value* and at what *seed* it will increment while creating the table. THAT's it.

So you cannot insert values for the `IDENTITY` column, as `SQL server` handles it for you.

`ID int identity(1, 2)` -- here (1 is starting value and 2 it will auto-increment by 2)

So it will look something like.

```
1

3

5

7
```

For more info, have a look at [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)